# Is there a more efficient way to create folders?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10

I am creating folders for each class to put resources in. The folder names for the classes follow the following (very original) format; 'Class (01), Class (02),..., Class (63)'.

I have used the following code to create the folders, but am looking for a more efficient method.

```
>>> import os
>>> path=r'C:\Users\Desktop\Classes\Class ('
>>> z=[str(i) for i in range(1,30)]
>>> folders=[path +z[i] +')' for i in range(len(z))]
>>> for i in range(len(folders)):
...     os.makedirs(folders[i])
```

I get the folders, but for classes 1-9 the folders names are 'Class (1) ... Class (9)'. Is there are way to get these names to be 'Class (01) ... Class (09)'?
Also, is there a more efficient way to make these folders? For some reason, i feel there are too many lines.

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.zfill` and `os.path.join`:

```
import os

path = '/pardir/'
folders = [os.path.join(path, "Class (%s)" % str(i).zfill(2)) for i in range(1,64)]
for folder in folders:
    os.makedirs(folder)

Output:
/pardir/Class (01)
/pardir/Class (02)
...
/pardir/Class (62)
/pardir/Class (63)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there are way to get these names to be 'Class (01) ... Class (09)'?

`f'{foo:02}'` will zero pad your number to 2 decimal places. If you need it to be dynamic you have to use `zfill`.

You don't need to create `z` or `folders` before hand.

How about this:

```
>>> import os
>>> path=r'C:\Users\Desktop\Classes\Class ('
>>> for i in range(1,30):
...     os.makedirs(f'{path}{i})')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a relatively modern Python version then you can specify left padding with the format string,

```
import os

for class_num in range(1, 30):
    folder_name = r"C:\Users\Desktop\Classes\Class ({:02d})".format(
        class_num
    )

    os.makedirs(folder_name)
```

Also you can avoid saving some of the intermediate values as lists.